# Семантика слов "крепкий" и "прочный"

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов, семантика, прилагательные, наречия

В каких прагматических контекстах употребляется прилагательное "крепкий", а в каких "прочный", если речь заходит о характеристиках конкретных объектов, не обязательно искусственных?

Предположения. Крепкий означает "в целом не подверженный разрушению, порче, сохранный". Прочный — "не подверженный повреждению в какой-то из своих частей". Так, если оказать давление иглой на какую-нибудь карту и она выдержит, можно говорить о ней, что она прочна. То же касается и снега, если он выдерживает какой-либо вес. Нить крепка, так как её трудно повредить, разъединить. Нить прочна, так как она в своих частях устойчива к разрыву.

Также интересуют различия между наречиями "прочно" и "крепко" в значении "устройства, конструирования, соединения чего-либо с чем-либо".

Предположения. "Крепко" сообщает о предпринятых усилиях. Крепко привинтить, приставить, пришить — проявить внутреннее психическое и физическое стремление к соединению. "Прочно" означает "с обеспечением износоустойчивости на некоторый срок". Прочно пришить, приставить, прилепить — так, чтобы было трудно разъединить, сломать, испортить.

Помогите разобраться в семантике этих слов в приведённом их значении.

Answer (score 1):

1. Если говорить о словоупотреблении в прямом смысле, то в быту эти два слова эквивалентны.

В научных же текстах чаще говорят "прочный". Скажем, "прочный бетон" или "прочные сорта стали". Слово "крепкий" в таком контексте не встретишь.

2. При этом, слово "крепкий" имеет более широкий диапазон переносных значений.

Например, в фильме "Андрей Рублёв" хан Едигей шутливо говорит звенигородскому князю:  "Крепко брата любишь?"

О врагах можно сказать (и в прямом и в переносном смысле): "крепко схватились".  Отсюда и уже чисто переносное "крепко поссорились".

Говорят также "крепко задумался". И иногда "крепко обиделся" или даже "затаил крепкую обиду".

А вот засевшая у меня в памяти цитата из речи (или письма?) молодого Первого Секретаря ЦК Компартии Украины Н. Хрущёва (цитирую по памяти): "Мы крепенько побили, да повыдёргивали затаившихся врагов народа."

Слово же "прочный" в переносном значении употребляется реже. Вот разве что "прочное основание" и "прочные связи".  Да ещё у Некрасова: "Умрешь не даром, дело прочно, Когда под ним струится кровь..."